# How do I get jQuery to animate from the last position to a new position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, jquery-animate

I have the following code used and tested in both Firefox and IE. Firefox works perfectly (move an element to a new location based on the current location) however IE fails. It **always** takes the **original** location and then animates to the desired location. The Firefox way is how I'd like it to work (move relative to the **current location** and not from the **original location**.

```js
$("a#pack1").click(function (){
     $('#solutions').animate({
      'background-position-x': '9px',
      'background-position-y': '8px'
     },1000,'linear');
     $('#content-data').animate({marginTop: "0px"}, 1000);
    });
    $("a#pack2").click(function (){
     $('#solutions').animate({
      'background-position-x': '9px',
      'background-position-y': '52px'
     },1000,'linear');
     $('#content-data').animate({marginTop: "-590px"}, 1000);
    });
    $("a#pack3").click(function (){
     $('#solutions').animate({
      'background-position-x': '9px',
      'background-position-y': '95px'
     },1000,'linear');
     $('#content-data').animate({marginTop: "-1150px"}, 1000);
    });
    $("a#pack4").click(function (){
     $('#solutions').animate({
      'background-position-x': '9px',
      'background-position-y': '138px'
     },1000,'linear');
     $('#content-data').animate({marginTop: "-1740px"}, 1000);
    });
    $("a#pack5").click(function (){
     $('#solutions').animate({
      'background-position-x': '9px',
      'background-position-y': '181px'
     },1000,'linear');
     $('#content-data').animate({marginTop: "-2397"}, 1000);
    });
    $("a#pack6").click(function (){
     $('#solutions').animate({
      'background-position-x': '9px',
      'background-position-y': '224px'
     },1000,'linear');
     $('#content-data').animate({marginTop: "-3064px"}, 1000);
    });
    $("a#pack7").click(function (){
     $('#solutions').animate({
      'background-position-x': '9px',
      'background-position-y': '268px'
     },1000,'linear');
     $('#content-data').animate({marginTop: "-3700px"}, 1000);
    });
    $("a#pack8").click(function (){
     $('#solutions').animate({
      'background-position-x': '9px',
      'background-position-y': '311px'
     },1000,'linear');
     $('#content-data').animate({marginTop: "-4256px"}, 1000);
    });
    $("a#pack9").click(function (){
     $('#solutions').animate({
      'background-position-x': '9px',
      'background-position-y': '350px'
     },1000,'linear');
     $('#content-data').animate({marginTop: "-4885px"}, 1000); //medical surveillance
    });
    $("a#pack10").click(function (){
     $('#solutions').animate({
      'background-position-x': '9px',
      'background-position-y': '394px'
     },1000,'linear');
     $('#content-data').animate({marginTop: "-5495px"}, 1000); //scheduler
    });
    $("a#pack11").click(function (){
     $('#solutions').animate({
      'background-position-x': '9px',
      'background-position-y': '438px'
     },1000,'linear');
     $('#content-data').animate({marginTop: "-6110px"},1000); //rehab reminder
    });
    $("a#pack12").click(function (){
     $('#solutions').animate({
      'background-position-x': '9px',
      'background-position-y': '480px'
     },1000,'linear');
     $('#content-data').animate({marginTop: "-6720px"}, 1000); //cost
    });
    $("a#pack13").click(function (){
     $('#solutions').animate({
      'background-position-x': '9px',
      'background-position-y': '525px'
     },1000,'linear');
     $('#content-data').animate({marginTop: "-7324px"}, 1000); //legal
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="solutions">
  <ul>
    <li><a id="pack1" href="javascript:void(0);">Leave</a></li>
     <li><a id="pack2" href="javascript:void(0);">Job Links</a></li>
     <li><a id="pack3" href="javascript:void(0);">Non Work Related</a></li>
     <li><a id="pack4" href="javascript:void(0);">Work Related</a></li>

     <li><a id="pack5" href="javascript:void(0);">Safety</a></li>
     <li><a id="pack6" href="javascript:void(0);">Ergonomics</a></li>
     <li><a id="pack7" href="javascript:void(0);">Industrial Hygiene</a></li>

     <li><a id="pack8" href="javascript:void(0);">Medical</a></li>
     <li><a id="pack9" href="javascript:void(0);">Medical Surveillance</a></li>
     <li><a id="pack10" href="javascript:void(0);">Scheduler</a></li>
     <li><a id="pack11" href="javascript:void(0);">Rehab Reminder</a></li>
     <li><a id="pack12" href="javascript:void(0);">Cost</a></li>
     <li><a id="pack13" href="javascript:void(0);">Legal</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Which version of IE?

Comment: You should really consider using CSS `transitions` combined with classes instead of jQuery `animate`. It would be way cleaner to do what you want.

Comment: @MasterYoda IE11

Comment: @Zenoo Can you help me with that solution? I'm not familiar.

Comment: Sure, give me some time to post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save quite a bit of code by passing the `background-position-x`, `background-position-y` and `margin-top` values through HTML attributes and adding a common class `pack` to your links like this :

```
<a id="pack1" class="pack" data-position-x="9px" data-position-y="8px" data-margin-top="0px" href="javascript:void(0);">Leave</a>
```

All you have to do next is add some transitions to your elements' CSS :

```css
#content-data{ transition: all 1s; }
#solutions{ transition: all 1s linear; }
```

And finally generalize your Javascript click handler to retrieve those attributes :

```
$("#solutions .pack").click(function() {
  $('#solutions').css({
    'background-position-x': $(this).attr('data-position-x'),
    'background-position-y': $(this).attr('data-position-y')
  });
  $('#content-data').css('margin-top', $(this).attr('data-margin-top'));
});
```

```js
$("#solutions .pack").click(function() {
  $('#solutions').css({
    'background-position-x': $(this).attr('data-position-x'),
    'background-position-y': $(this).attr('data-position-y')
  });
  $('#content-data').css('margin-top', $(this).attr('data-margin-top'));
});
```

```css
#content-data{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 1s;
}

#solutions{
  background-image: url(https://bennettfeely.com/gradients/img/gradient_24.png);
  background-position: 0 0;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="solutions">
  <ul>
    <li><a id="pack1" class="pack" data-position-x="9px" data-position-y="8px" data-margin-top="0px" href="javascript:void(0);">Leave</a></li>
    <li><a id="pack2" class="pack" data-position-x="9px" data-position-y="52px" data-margin-top="100px" href="javascript:void(0);">Job Links</a></li>
    <li><a id="pack3" class="pack" data-position-x="9px" data-position-y="95px" data-margin-top="200px" href="javascript:void(0);">Non Work Related</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="content-data"></div>
```

Comment: I mean, I know it is supposed to animate (using transition) but it just jumps to the next location, it doesn't animate as expected.

Comment: @dihakz It&#39;s already animated with the CSS rule `transition: all 1s`, as you can see in the snippet.

Comment: Yes, I saw that - but mine is not transitioning (animating) as yours is. Is there something different between the HTML/jQuery/CSS that you specified for me and what you have in the snippet?

Comment: Update: it IS working in IE, but not Firefox now! In FF it just skips right to the next position (while your snippet does not)

Comment: @dihakz The code I specified for you is a summary of the snippet. Maybe try to add `background-position: 0 0` like done in the snippet.

Comment: ugh... this is the most embarrassing thing to ever say: I did not delete my cache! it's working everywhere now - thank you!

Comment: @dihakz No problem, have fun with your project.

Answer (score 1):

there is a kind of dirty hack with this.
You can animate a div with it's background crossbrowserfriendly p.e. like this with a absolute div (#bg) inside:

```
<div id="solutions">
<div id="bg"></div>
<ul>
        <li><a id="pack1" class="test" href="javascript:void(0);">Leave</a></li>
            <li><a id="pack2" class="test" href="javascript:void(0);">Job Links</a></li>
            <li><a id="pack3" class="test" href="javascript:void(0);">Non Work Related</a></li>
            <li><a id="pack4" class="test" href="javascript:void(0);">Work Related</a></li>


    </ul>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/actree/1jaek93z/)